# A SELECT Query works fine with a subquery which SELECTS , but when DELETE is applied to the same sub query, it is not working

Tags: sql-server

Assuming  `Employee(Empid,name,salary)` exists with duplicate records with Empid,name,salary in an SQL Server 2017 table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Employee') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #Employee

CREATE TABLE #Employee 
(
     Empid INT, 
     name VARCHAR(250), 
     salary FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO #Employee 
VALUES  (1008, 'Biju Joseph', 8500),
        (1008, 'Biju Joseph', 8500),
        (1008, 'Haris', 9000),
        (1009, 'John', 9500),
        (1009, 'John', 9500),
        (1010, 'SMITH', 10500)
```

This nested query is working fine to `SELECT` (with SQL Server 2017):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         name,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, salary ORDER BY name) cnt 
     FROM  
         employee) mytable 
WHERE 
    cnt > 1
```

but, when try to DELETE, it is showing an error message:

```
(DELETE FROM <tablename> WHERE <expression>)

DELETE FROM 
    (SELECT 
         name,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, salary ORDER BY name) cnt 
     FROM 
         employee) mytable 
WHERE cnt > 1
```

Errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
>   Incorrect syntax near 'mytable'

Please note : when using a CTE, or other subqueries, I am able to `DELETE`, but what I am missing in this particular subquery, when trying to `DELETE`?

Comment: You have to reference the alias of the derived table in your delete. i.e `delete [mytable] from (...`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using the Common Table Expression(CTE).

Try the code below :

```
;WITH Duplicate (Name, Counts) AS
(
    SELECT 
        name, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, salary ORDER BY name) 
    FROM 
        #Employee
)
DELETE FROM Duplicate  
WHERE Counts > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   DELETE C
   FROM 
           (SELECT name,row_number() OVER
              (PARTITION BY name,salary
               ORDER BY name)cnt FROM employee                 
           ) C 
           where C.cnt>1
```

I recommend using a CTE

Comment: That is not a CTE, it is a derived table. A CTE starts with "WITH" and precedes the statement (select, etc.) that references it.

Comment: I know, this is a sub query as you can see but using a CTE is a better option in this case